# Expression evaluation - avoiding a StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, algorithm, stack, binary-tree

I had been fiddling around to build my own expression evaluator and landed up at this issue i am curious about.

I have used 2 ways of evaluating a string expression. One method uses a Binary tree.

When i enter an expression string of length greater than (approx.) 42000, i get a stackoverflow exception.

However the same does not happen if i evaluate the same expression string (even of **much** longer length) with this function (my second implementation)

Now i would prefer to stick to the Binary tree method - is there a way i can fix the Stack overflow exception, i.e. i can avoid my Stack overflow in recursion or is there a way to find when the Stack will actually overflow? If not, how can i actually *at least* warn the user before even the expression starts getting evaluated that a Stack overflow can happen?

Comment: have you considered reparsing your string to reverse polish notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), this would then allow you to do this with much less complextity

Comment: What does the parameter `string strPostFix` mean for you then?

Comment: I did wonder about that, in which case your binary tree is unfortunately the completely wrong method for processing this, its Bodmas style maths that need the tree to analyse. so your second solution is the correct one

Comment: @MikeT :: You are not aware i guess - but i would like to tell you that a Binary expression tree is built keeping precedence in mind. My precedence issue has already been taken care of when i convert expression to RPN. I believe you are not aware how the method works. Both my implementations are giving me perfect results - its only the stack which overflows causes issues for a humungous string.

Comment: Since you're already using RPN, both methods are internally doing essentially the same thing, it's just that the stack-based method is (ironically) using the runtime library's heap (which can grow essentially to the size of addressable RAM), while in processing a binary tree you are (I assume) using recursion, which stores data on the CPU's stack for each nested invocation, and the CPU stack is typically much more limited -- my old MSVC++ 2008 compiler makes .EXEs with just 1Mb of stack by default.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, your best bet is to use the second method. While a recursion is usable here, from an algorithm standpoint, the stack method that you provided is more correct - Mainly because your binary tree method doesn't have a way to deal with unary operators (as far as I can tell, at least) (e.g., ++i).

As for your first question, there isn't really a way to tell if something will throw a stack overflow exception from just input. Your best bet would be to just wrap the first call to the recursive method in a try/catch, and explicitly catch the StackOverflowException, and return a valid error message to the user.

Also, keep in mind, you could theoretically move the binary tree implementation to use a stack object similar to number 2, if you wanted. Although you'd still have to redesign the method to use your stack instead of the application's stack.